# align two rows of buttons in css

Tags: css, html

I need 2 rows of buttons, in row 1 I will have 3 buttons, in row 2 there will be 5 buttons. I would like them to be nicely aligned, so that row1->button1 has the edge at the same horizontal point as row2->button1, the same with last button in both rows and right edge.

I might be misunderstanding something about css/html, but I have completely no idea why buttons in each row go to the next line:

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="buttonsRow">
        <div class="button-wrapper" style="width: 33.3%">
            <button>1.1</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-wrapper" style="width: 33.3%">
            <button>1.2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-wrapper" style="width: 33.3%">
            <button>1.3</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonsRow">
        <div class="button-wrapper" style="width: 20%">
            <button>2.1</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-wrapper" style="width: 20%">
            <button>2.2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-wrapper" style="width: 20%">
            <button>2.3</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-wrapper" style="width: 20%">
            <button>2.4</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-wrapper" style="width: 20%">
            <button>2.5</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS for that:

```
.footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #66CCFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.buttonsRow{
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.button-wrapper{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

button{
    height: 33px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

When I am checking this in Firefox, the first .buttonsRow has width of 701px (no padding, border or margin), and each of the 3 .button-wrappers inside is 233px wide (again, no padding border or margin).
Now the maths I have learned in school tells me: 3*233 = 699. 699 < 701.
Wouldn't that mean it will fit in the row? And so why it doesn't?
Here is jsfiddle btw: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zZ3F/4/)

Comment: You just need to [remove the space between the inline elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because inline elements are sensitive to white space. Remove it like this:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5zZ3F/5/)**

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="buttonsRow">
        <div class="button-wrapper" style="width: 33.3%">
            <button>1.1</button>
        </div><div class="button-wrapper" style="width: 33.3%">
            <button>1.2</button>
        </div><div class="button-wrapper" style="width: 33.3%">
            <button>1.3</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonsRow">
        <div class="button-wrapper" style="width: 20%">
            <button>2.1</button>
        </div><div class="button-wrapper" style="width: 20%">
            <button>2.2</button>
        </div><div class="button-wrapper" style="width: 20%">
            <button>2.3</button>
        </div><div class="button-wrapper" style="width: 20%">
            <button>2.4</button>
        </div><div class="button-wrapper" style="width: 20%">
            <button>2.5</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or, float the button-wrappers left:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/K4886/)**